# How to make a Customtkinter ComboBox with dependencies

Tags: python, combobox, customtkinter

I am using customtkinter to create 3 comboboxes which contain a list of Model Groups with the models and buckets for each. So I want to basically be able to choose the group in the first dropdown box which in turn will populate the second with the available models and then the final dropdown box with the available buckets. However with ctk.CTkCombobox it does not seem to function the same way as tk.Combobox does as the models and buckets drop down boxes don't populate once I select my group. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code that I have tried with no luck.

see the dictionary below please

```
models_data = {
"Caterpillar LHD models": {
    "R1300G": ["DB 3.4", "DB 2.8", "DB 2.5", "DB 3.1"],
    "R1600H": ["DB 5.9", "DB 4.8", "DB 4.2", "DB 5.6"],
    "R1700": ["DB 5.7", "DB 6.1", "DB 6.6", "DB 7.5", "DB 8"],
    "R1700XE": ["DB 5.7", "DB 6.1", "DB 6.6", "DB 7.5"],
    "R1700G": ["DB 4.6", "DB 5", "DB 6.6", "DB 5.7", "DB 7.3", "DB 8.8"],
    "R2900G": ["DB 8.9", "DB 7.2", "DB 6.3", "DB 8.3"],
    "R2900": ["DB 6.3", "DB 7.2", "DB 8.3", "DB 8.9"],
    "R2900XE": ["DB 7.4", "DB 8.6", "DB 9.2", "DB 9.8"],
    "R3000H": ["DB 10.5", "DB 8.9", "DB 9.5"]
},
"Sandvik LHD models": {
    "SANDVIK LH517i": ["DB 7", "DB 7.6", "DB 8.6", "DB 9.1", "DB 8.4"],
    "SANDVIK LH621i": ["DB 8.0", "DB 9.0", "DB 10.7", "DB 11.2"],
    "SANDVIK LH515i": ["DB 6.3", "DB 6.8", "DB 7.5"],
    "SANDVIK LH514": ["DB 6.2", "DB 7", "DB 5.4"],
    "Toro™ LH625iE": ["DB 10"],
    "Sandvik LH514E": ["DB 4.6", "DB 5", "DB 5.4", "DB 6.2", "DB 7"],
    "Toro™ LH514BE": ["DB 4.6", "DB 5", "DB 5.4", "DB 6.2", "DB 7", "DB 7.5"],
    "Sandvik LH409E": ["DB 3.8", "DB 4.3", "DB 4.6"]
},
    "Epiroc LHD models": { "Epiroc ST14 SG": ["DB 4.7", "DB 5", "DB 5.4", "DB 5.8", "DB 6.4", "DB 7.0", "DB 7.8"],
    "Epiroc ST18 SG": ["DB 9.7", "DB 8.8", "DB 7.9", "DB 7.3", "DB 6.7", "DB 6.3"],
    "Epiroc ST14": ["DB 4.7", "DB 5", "DB 5.4", "DB 5.8", "DB 6.4", "DB 7.0", "DB 7.8"],
    "Epiroc ST18 S": ["DB 9.7", "DB 8.8", "DB 7.9", "DB 7.3", "DB 6.7", "DB 6.3"]
},
"Komatsu LHD models": {
    "WX18H": ["DB 8.2", "DB 9.2", "DB 10", "DB 11.2"],
    "WX22H": ["DB 10", "DB 11", "DB 12.2", "DB 13.8"]
}
```

So I have setup some definitions as such

```
def on_group_selected(col):
    selected_group = group_vars[col].get()
    model_dropdowns[col]['values'] = list(models_data[selected_group].keys())
    model_vars[col].set("")
    buckets_dropdowns[col]['values'] = []

def on_model_selected(col):
    selected_group = group_vars[col].get()
    selected_model = model_vars[col].get()
    if selected_model != "":
        bucket_values = models_data[selected_group][selected_model]
        buckets_dropdowns[col]['values'] = bucket_values
```

I have setup the labels as such

```
   # Group dropdown
    group_var = ctk.StringVar()
    group_var.set(list(models_data.keys())[col])
    group_vars.append(group_var)
    group_dropdown = ctk.CTkComboBox(column_frame, variable=group_var, 
    values=list(models_data.keys()),font=("Univers-Light-Normal", 10), width=200, 
    justify="center", command=on_model_selected)
    group_dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, col=col: on_group_selected(col))
    group_dropdown.pack(pady=10)

    # Model dropdown
    model_var = ctk.StringVar()
    model_var.set("Select Model")
    model_vars.append(model_var)
    model_dropdown = ctk.CTkComboBox(column_frame, variable=model_var, values=[], font=("Univers- 
    Light-Normal", 10), width=200)
    model_dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, col=col: on_model_selected(col))
    model_dropdown.pack(pady=10)
    model_dropdowns.append(model_dropdown)

    # Buckets dropdown
    buckets_var = ctk.StringVar()
    buckets_var.set("")
    buckets_dropdown = ctk.CTkComboBox(column_frame, variable=buckets_var, values=[],font= 
    ("Univers-Light-Normal", 10)  ,width=80)
    buckets_dropdown.pack(pady=10)
    buckets_dropdowns.append(buckets_dropdown)
```